# Logging in PHP using XAMPP

Tags: php, logging

I am creating a web solution in PHP (XAMPP). Especially when I do AJAX calls, I cannot echo to debug as it is not bringing output adding to the echo for return JSON object. Is there a logging mechanism prevalent in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is a function named `error_log`
official description: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: Great! It looks like one can specifies the destination file for logs to be written.The name says error_log, Is this being used for debug and error messages? Is there a way to switch this off (i am thinking live here)

Comment: yes it's used primarily for debug and error messages, but I don't know if there is some way to disable it